# What is LINKEDIT Block

Tags: instruments

I have been doing performance measurement on my app and I see a sizeable amount allocated to _LINKEDIT block and I just wished to know if any one knows about it. 
Thanks 
Sudeep Dua

Answer (score 2):

> The __LINKEDIT segment contains raw data used by the dynamic linker,
>   such as symbol, string, and relocation table entries.

You can find more info about it here:
https://github.com/aidansteele/osx-abi-macho-file-format-reference

Comment: Thank you Gene Z. Appreciate it!